# Why can't galavanic cells run without an electrolyte?

Tags: electrochemistry

If all that needs to happen in a galvanic cell is transfer of electrons from one electrode to another, why can't we just join them directly? What is it that the electrolyte does that keeps the cell running that doesn't happen without it?

I actually tried to ponder about this myself and came up with my own theory, i just need someone to confirm/correct my theory.

Considering a Daniel cell, copper electrode is dipped in let's say copper sulphate and connected to zinc electrode which is dipped in say zinc sulphate solution, a salt bridge is also setup, what happens is that copper having a higher standard potential starts pulling electrons from neutral zinc and the copper ions being positive start getting greedy and deposit on the electrode for those electrons, meanwhile zinc gets ionized and starts dissolving in the electrolyte, the free sulphate ions in copper side start jumping into the sea of zinc ions on the zinc side(technically its just one sulphate ion nudging other sulphate ions in a sequence which go and form zinc sulphate on the zinc side). This is what I **think** happens in a galvanic cell.

Now, since in dry form if the electrodes are just connected directly, the copper will be stronger on both ends of the circuit and there is no current as a result.

Edit: There has been a suggestion of a different already published answer, but it doesn't give a clear explanation enough, if someone could give a clear step by step journey of the workings of a galvanic cell and functions of its key components, I shall be grateful. Thank you.

Comment: Rhetorical question: Where would dry electrodes take the energy from? Daniell cell takes it from reaction $\ce{Zn + Cu^2+ -> Zn^2+ + Cu}$.The respective electrode reversible half-reactions act as charge pumps, similarly as electronic charge pumps are used in chip to generate various voltage levels.

Comment: [What is the Purpose of an Electrolyte in a Galvanic Cell?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/44469/what-is-the-purpose-of-an-electrolyte-in-a-galvanic-cell)

Comment: "join them directly": you can do that. It's called a *short circuit*. ;)

Comment: Most textbooks or online educational sources give such explanations. Study them and come with what you do not understand. See e.g. https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Book%3A_ChemPRIME_(Moore_et_al.)/17%3A_Electrochemical_Cells

Answer (score 1):

> If all that needs to happen in a galvanic cell is transfer of
> electrons from one electrode to another, why can't we just join them
> directly?

Obviously, this is only a partial explanation; not only must electrons be transferred, but there must be chemical changes at the electrode surface as well.

If you were to join *dry* copper and zinc plates, there will be a development contact potential. This is explained very well in Wikipedia [Galvani potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvani_potential). However, one cannot extract useful work just from this transient contact potential. So this arrangment is useless as an electrochemical cell.

In order to draw continuous current from a cell for doing external work say in a bulb, there must be a chemical change. This means that the electrode material must ionize, say if you have a Zn electrode, leading to the formation of $\ce{Zn^{2+}}$ ions. As you know, charged ions alone do not have a long lifetime. For example, if you wanted to create a doubly ionized zinc ion directly from zinc, you would probably require the surface temperature of the Sun in the gas phase. However, presence of a solution makes ionization easy. A solution phase stabilizes ions.

Alternatively, one also requires a solution and a salt bridge because air is a poor conductor of electricity. All you need is a *medium* for holding ions in an electrochemical cell, and for that purposes an aqueous solution in Daniell cell is a good idea. Also, note that ordinary "dry cells" in the market are not dry at all. The internal stuff is very moist.

A final advice is to avoid anthropomorphizing non-living objects. Copper ions are not not greedy like humans, sulfate ions don't nudge and copper is not strong like a superman :-) These labels create problems in proper scientific explanations.

Comment: @ AChem. What do you mean with the sentence "sulfate ions don't nudge" ? In the Merriam-Webster Dictionary, the word "to nudge" is defined as : "to push gently (as with the elbow) in order to seek attention". So what ?

Answer (score 1):

A cell $\ce{Zn/Cu}$ contains two separate compartments, one with a $\ce{Zn}$ plate dipped in a $\ce{ZnSO4}$ solution, and then another compartment made of a copper plate dipped in a $\ce{CuSO4}$ solution. If they are separated, nothing will happen, even if the the metal plates are connected by a copper wire.
Matter of fact, during the first microsecond, some zinc atoms will produce some $\ce{Zn^{2+}}$ ions in solution and electrons in the outer wire, by the reaction $$\ce{Zn -> Zn^{2+} + 2 e^-}$$ And the electrons will travel to the copper plate and discharge some $\ce{Cu^{2+}}$ ions according to : $$\ce{Cu^{2+} + 2 e^- -> Cu}$$ But these two reactions will only last a couple of microseconds and then stop. The reason is that the zinc solution contains now some positive charges, so that it becomes more and more positively charged. This supplement of positive charges will prevent new zinc atoms to produce new positive ions (and new electrons). The same thing happens on the copper plate, where arriving electrons will destroy copper ions, without removing $\ce{SO4^{2-}}$ ions. The copper solution becomes more and more negatively charged, which repels new electrons and prevents them from coming to the copper plate. The cell does not work.

In order for the cell to work, it is necessary to get rid of the positive charges due to newly created $\ce{Zn^{2+}}$ ions in the zinc compartment. And to get rid of the sulfate ions from the copper compartment.

The only way to do it is to make up a liquid bridge between the two compartments. This bridge is made of a solution of non reacting ions, like $\ce{Na+ + SO4^{2-}}$. With this setup, the positive ions in excess in the first compartment attracts the negative ions in excess in the second compartment, and they may join in the bridge, so as to establish electric neutrality everywhere. The cell is now working properly.